# Azure - VM snapshot restore

Tags: azure

On hyper-v VM snapshots are easy to work with - you create it, make any changes you want, run a revert snapshot and that's it, VM is back to the snapshot state.

I want to understand if Azure has this as well?
All I'm reading is around New-AzureRmSnapshot cmdlet, but I don't see a basic revert scenario.
From what I found, it's all about restoring snapshot to a new vm and other scenarios, but I want a simply revert of an azure vm and be done.

Thank you for any pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I found, it's all about restoring snapshot to a new vm and
>   other scenarios,

You are right, restore Azure VM snapshot works as restore data to new disk then use this disk to create a new VM.

For now, Azure does **not** support restore snapshot like hyper-V.

As a workaround, after new VM created, you can stop original VM, then change the IP address to the old one, in this way, you can use this new VM.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [How to revert an azure disk back to its former snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811062/how-to-revert-an-azure-disk-back-to-its-former-snapshot/60358922#60358922)

I added my answer there, describing how to do it with Azure PowerShell.